# Convert Access TRANSFORM/PIVOT query to SQL Server 2012

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012

I need help converting this MS Access query to SQL Server 2012:

```
TRANSFORM 
SUM(TTQTY * qty) AS quantity 
SELECT matlprodcode AS product_code, cvend_name AS supplier, CITMCD AS material, matldesc AS description, MIN(unit_cost) AS unit_cost 
FROM acs_Budget 
WHERE matlprodcode NOT LIKE ';I8*' 
AND matlprodcode NOT LIKE 'I1' 
GROUP BY matlprodcode, cvend_name, CITMCD, matldesc 
PIVOT budgetmonth;
```

I have tried converting it myself here:

```
SELECT matlprodcode AS product_code, 
    cvend_name AS supplier, 
    CITMCD AS material, 
    matldesc AS 'description', 
    MIN(unit_cost) AS unit_cost 
FROM
(
   SELECT TTQTY, qty, matlprodcode, cvend_name, CITMCD, matldesc, unit_cost, budgetmonth FROM acs_Budget WHERE matlprodcode NOT LIKE ';I8*' AND matlprodcode NOT LIKE 'I1' 
) AS T
PIVOT
(
   SUM(TTQTY * qty)
) P
```

Is this correct? Any suggestions? Or am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself. I am not sure if this will help others but here is the final query that will work in SQL Server. I converted this from MS Access:

```
SELECT pt.* FROM 
(SELECT SUM(TTQTY * qty) AS quantity, matlprodcode AS product_code, cvend_name AS supplier, CITMCD as material, matldesc AS description, MIN(unit_cost) AS unit_cost, budgetmonth 
FROM acs_Budget 
WHERE matlprodcode NOT LIKE ';I8*' 
AND matlprodcode NOT LIKE 'I1' 
GROUP BY matlprodcode, cvend_name, CITMCD, matldesc, budgetmonth) AS src 
PIVOT (MIN(quantity) FOR src.budgetmonth IN ([4/1/2015], [5/1/2015], [6/1/2015], [7/1/2015], [8/1/2015], [9/1/2015], [10/1/2015], [11/1/2015], [12/1/2015], [1/1/2016], [2/1/2016], [3/1/2016])) AS pt;
```

Some things that helped me:

- First I selected everything that I wanted to see. Including what MS Access was transforming and pivoting.
- Then I found out what each column MS Access was pivoting, in this case the quantity.
- So I did a MIN of the quantity because the PIVOT needs an aggregated function.
- After the aggregated function you need the actual PIVOT that MS Access is using which goes after the FOR.
- Then I did something similar to a SELECT DISTINCT budgetmonth FROM acs_Budget to get each item I could pivot by and that's where the IN came in.

Not sure if I explained very well but this is how I got mine to work!